# Can Mognet quests be accessed over Wireless Communication?

Tags: final-fantasy-3

I'm really sorry for being vague. I've improved my question:

In Final Fantasy III, there are extra quests to unlock extra content, such as the Legendary Smith and the Onion Knight job. To access these quests, you need to send 7 mail to another player. Once you do that, you must send mail to NPCs.
You can send mail over WiFi to another WiFi-connected DS. This is referred to "sending mail to a far away friend." You can also send it with the DS Wireless system with the same method they use with PictoChat.

If I have a friend with a DS and a Final Fantasy III game  card, can I send 7 mail to him over the wireless and still get the quests, or do I have to use WiFi?

Comment: @scienceguyz - What platform are you playing FF3 on?  The MogNet stuff is only available on the DS version.

Comment: http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Mognet_(Final_Fantasy_III) - for anyone confused by the question.

Comment: @JasonBerkan I'm using DS Lite

Answer (score 2):

The Nearby Friend option uses the same method of communication as the chat room in the DS System so you shouldn't need a wireless internet connection to use it

As for the sidequest, that would refer to sending mail to the other ingame characters, you can see which ones give you an Ultimate Weapon sidequest and which one gives you the Onion Knight sidequest (Ultimate class and tribute to the base class 'Onion Kid' from the original Final Fantasy III)

EDIT: i should note that these quest shouldn't need a connection to do since you obtain them from the ingame character mails

Comment: I just improved my question. Also, I know everything about the side quests through videos, except the guy I learned it from used AR codes to get the 7 mail.